# How to get a nested child record to know stuff about its parent during instantiation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form for creating a new `invoice` with many `items`.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :number, :date, :recipient, :items_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

Now when I instantiate a new `invoice` and a set of containing `items`, I want these `items` to *know* something about the `invoice` they belong to even before they are saved, so I can do something like this in my `Item` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  after_initialize :set_hourly_rate

  private 

    def set_hourly_rate
      if new_record?
        self.price ||= invoice.project.hourly_rate
      end
    end   

end
```

Right now, my code fails because the child (`item`) doesn't know anything about its parent (`invoice`) during instantiation. Only after saving the `invoice` (and thus its nested `items`), it all works out. But I want to set a default value on each new item even **before** it gets saved.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback on the invoice association, as follows:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Code
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :items, :after_add => :set_item_price

  private

  def set_item_price(item)
    item.price = project.hourly_rate
  end  

end
```

Comment: Oh excellent, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for... I just wonder if it is good coding practice to have a method `set_item_hourly_rate` in my `Invoice` model? Anyway, I am going to do it like this...

Comment: I agree that it's not entirely clean, but the issue with nested attributes, is that everything is wrapped in a transaction. Because of this, you don't have access to the parent even in the `after_create` callback. Having this said, I just don't see any better way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem with this approach is that `set_item_price` gets triggered every time the `edit` view gets rendered, e.g. on validation. Is there a way to run it only once, when calling the `new` action?

Comment: I guess you'll have to check if it's a new record by hand. `item.price = project.hourly_rate if item.new_record?`

Comment: OK, that is pretty much what I ended up doing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `invoice` object, you can create children records with the `.items.build` method ([docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many))
`items` created through this method should have a reference to the `invoice`
Though, I think they will have the reference only if the Invoice has been persisted (not really sure about that.)